# Why do I get an error calling a module in an always block?

Tags: verilog

I have a module `temp1` in Verilog as below:

```
module temp1;
---
---
---
endmodule
```

I want to call this module instance from other module `temp2`. However, I want to this always at the positive edge of the clock-

```
module temp2(clk);
    input clk;
    always @(posedge clk)
        temp1 t1;
endmodule
```

This gives me a syntax error. It seems I should not call any module from within the `always` block. Is it true that we cannot create instance of a module from within the `always` block? If yes, how can I do this in some other way as I have to call `temp1` only when at the `posedge` of the clock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In verilog, when you are **instantiating** a module, that means you are adding extra **hardware** to the board.

This hardware **must be** added **before simulation starts**(i.e. at compile time). Here, you can **not** add/remove hardware at each clock pulse.

Once instantiated, the module is executed/checked for **each timestamp** of simulation, till the end.

So to execute any module, *just instantiate it*, providing the clk and other required inputs to it, and **add the always block in the sub-module itself**.

```
module temp2(clk);
    input clk;
        temp1 t1(clk); // note the input port clk here
endmodule

module temp(input clk);
    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
    // ...
    end
endmodule
```

Verilog provides a **generate** block for creating **multiple instances** of the same module.

```
genvar i;  // note special genvar type, used in generate block
generate
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
temp t1[i];  // create 5 instances of temp module
endgenerate
```

**Side Note:**

You may have mixed the understanding about **module instantiation** and calling of **task/function**. Module is a **static entity** while task/function can be **dynamic** ones. As you showed, *if* temp is a **task**, then the above call is valid.

```
task temp;
// ...
endtask: temp

module temp2(clk);
    input clk;
    always @(posedge clk)
        temp1(); // task/function temp
endmodule
```

More information on **instantiation** can be obtained from [Verilog Module Instantiation](http://verilog.renerta.com/mobile/source/vrg00027.htm), [Instantiating Modules and Primitives](http://support.ema-eda.com/search/eslfiles/default/main/sl_legacy_releaseinfo/staging/sl3/release_info/psd142/veriaref/chap10.html), [Structural Modelling](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjACahUKEwiiwbmgq5LJAhUEJI4KHcE-BGY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wiley.com%2Flegacy%2Fwileychi%2Fmblin%2Fsupp%2Fstudent%2FLN06HierarchicalModeling.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFafpIm8Z2BwL2O_k0hXVqzSVxVYA&bvm=bv.107467506,d.c2E) links.

Comment: Thanks but say if I have to call a module only at the first positive edge of the clock and then I dont want to call it. In that case how can I do this?Because calling module in initial block wont work. And I dont want to put initial in my module because putting `initial @(posedge clk)` doesnt make sense

Comment: This can be done by setting some flags in module. Like `always @(posedge clk) begin if(!flag) begin flag <=1; // ... other logic here... end end`. But this is just an ugly workaround. Still your module is bound to be present.

Comment: Can you show some code. It would be good to have a task/function instead of module. Calling the function seems to be a better idea

Comment: Actually I got the idea..I used a temporary flag and it worked.Thanks a lot