# Verilog - Calling a module inside a case statement

Tags: verilog, case-statement

I'm not that familiar in Verilog but can you call another module when it's inside a case statement?

Comment: A somewhat similar question on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719071/error-while-using-always-block-in-verilog/33719290). You can have generate block also.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call a module just as you do in C language, since it's not a function, you **instantiate** it.
If you want to instantiate a module, you should use `generate`.

Edit: An example of using `generate` with a case statement can be found [here](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/How-to-use-verilog-quot-generate-quot-inside-a-case/td-p/514285).

2nd edit: If you just wanted to call a section of code in a case-statement then you can create a **task** or a **function**. More information [here](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/task_func1.html). (credit goes to [Hida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3848887/hida))

Comment: To add to this: If you just wanted to call a section of code in a case-statement then you can create a task or a function. More information [here](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/task_func1.html).

Comment: Indeed. If you don't mind, I can append it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can not call module within case statement , but you can create function and then call in case statement (task is not synthesizeble)