# Syntax error near "generate" and "endgenerate" in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am new in Verilog and I am trying to implement single precision floating point addition-subtraction using verilog. I am getting an error which I am unable to correct. Can anyone please help me?

module addModule(Rs,Re,Rm,As,Ae,Am,Bs,Be,Bm);

```
//Declarations of ports
  Rs,Re,Rm;
  As,Bs;
  input [7:0] Ae,Be;
  input [22:0] Am,Bm;

reg [7:0] Re;
reg [22:0] Rm;
reg Rs;
//wire declarations.
wire [23:-1] C;
assign C[-1] = 0;
wire [23:1] sum;
//variable declaration.
genvar count;

always @(*)
begin
//Add two mantissas.
if ((As^Bs)==0)
    begin
        generate   //getting error here "Syntax error near "generate"."
        for(count=0;count<24;count=count+1)
            begin
                add add_1(.c_out(C[count]),.sum(sum[count]),.in1(tempAm[count]),.in2(tempBm[count]),.c_in(C[count-1]));
            end
        endgenerate   //syntax error near "endgenerate"
    end

else
    begin
        generate   //Syntax error near "generate".
        for(count=0;count<24;count=count+1)
            begin
                subtract sub_1(.c_out(C[count]),.dif(sum[count]),.in1(tempAm[count]),.in2(tempBm[count]),.c_in(C[count]));
            end
        endgenerate   //Syntax error near "endgenerate".
    end


end
endmodule
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Instances (ie `subtract sub_1`) do not go inside `always` or `initial` blocks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Verilog, when you are **instantiating** a module, that means you are adding extra **hardware** to the board.

This hardware must be added **before simulation starts**(i.e. at compile time). Here, you can **not** add/remove hardware at each clock pulse.

Once instantiated, the module is executed/checked for **each timestamp** of simulation, till the end.

So to execute any module, just instantiate it, providing the clk and other required inputs to it, and **add the always block in the sub-module itself**.

Once the hardware is *instantiated*, it shall be executed according to the logic inside it, *for entire life time*.

Here you are instantiating module at **wrong place**. The use of `generate` block must be done **outside** any procedural blocks.

```
// generate outside any other blocks
   generate   
    for(count=0;count<24;count=count+1)
        begin
            add add_1(.c_out(C[count]),.sum(sum[count]),.in1(tempAm[count]),.in2(tempBm[count]),.c_in(C[count-1]));
        end
    endgenerate

always @(*)
begin
// Other stuff here.
end
```

If you want to **manipulate input signals** of the `subtract sub_1` module, simply manipulate `C`,`sum` and other variables declared in `addModule` module. Since they are connected, the change shall **reflect** in `subtract sub_1` module too.

For more information on generate block, refer [Module Instantiation](http://verilog.renerta.com/mobile/source/vrg00027.htm), [Generate block example](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/verilog2k2.html) and a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719071/error-while-using-always-block-in-verilog/33719290) links.

Comment: I want to call add module or subtract module depending on the condition in the if block is satisfied or not. I tried defining generate block in two tasks one for calling add module and another for calling subtract module above always @(*) and calling the task in the if else block but it is still not working.

Comment: @vishnupriya You do not **CALL** modules you **instantiate** them. Your describing hardware not writing software. You have to make add and subtract always exist, then select the output of which one you want to use.

Comment: Module is instantiated once at the beginning of simulation. As Morgan pointed out Modules represent physical hardware while task and functions are used to calculate repetitive code. In your case, there can be a workaround to add a signal/wire as input to each of modules `add` and `subtract`. The operations are performed only when value of control wire goes high. For eg. the wire goes high state when `As^Bs=1` and the addition is performed. While giving invert of same wire to `sub1` module. There can be other logic too. Yet in any case, the generate blocks need to be outside procedural blocks.

Comment: Thanx a lot. Got it finally. I instantiated both the add and subtract modules outside the always block and used an extra input clk for controlling the execution of operations in the sub-modules.